# PHP is_dir doesn't recognize a directory that it created

Tags: php

I have a PHP script for uploading files to a server. The files are to be sorted by the name of the submitter just for my own internal convenience. My script checks if the target directory exists, and if it doesn't, it creates the directory. Thus:

```
$abort = false;
$targetDir = 'uploads/' . $userName;
if (!is_dir($targetDir)) {
    if(!mkdir($targetDir)) {
        echo '<p>Can''t create ' . $targetDir . '</p>';
        $abort = true;
    }
}
if (!$abort) {
    move_uploaded_file(...)
}
```

The first time I access this code (when the target directory doesn't exist), it operates correctly, creating the desired target directory, and moving the uploaded file to the desired directory.

Every subsequent time, I hit the "Can't create..." error.

Using my FTP client, I can see that the target directory has been created, with permissions 0755, so any user should have permission to at least see the file (not that this should be relevant since the same "user" that created the file (the PHP pseudo-user) is the user trying to access it.

Why doesn't "is_dir" recognize this newly created directory?

Comment: Check your file permissions. The problem is likely that your script created the directory with the wrong permissions.

Comment: The directory is created with permissions (0755) (as noted in the original question). I have verified this through my FTP client.

Comment: Never mind. Stupid typo in PHP and its stupid automagically created variables!!

Comment: *automagically created variables* what are they?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your echo: Fixed here...

```
    $abort = false;
    $targetDir = 'uploads/' . $userName;
    if (!is_dir($targetDir)) {
        if(!mkdir($targetDir)) {
            echo "<p>Can't create " . $targetDir . "</p>";
            $abort = true;
        }
    }
    if (!$abort) {
        move_uploaded_file(...)
    }
```

Comment: This is true, but doesn't actually answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

My actual code contained a stupid typo that meant I was not actually checking for the existence of $targetDir, I was checking for the existence of $targeDir. I really wish PHP had a way to turn off automatic variables.